# Javascript Load Data From Another Page Inside A Function Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, jsp

I am working on google map move markers (multiple markers). I am using like this function for show markers.

```
 setInterval(
 function addMarker() 
 {
 <%=arackoord%>
 }
 ,1000);
```

<%=arackoord%> is in the same page like this return :

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
 {position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.858231, 30.746574),
 map: map}); markers.push(marker);
```

SeInterval is not working because in the same page, arackoord is not updating itself. So I did another page which exacly same output like this (no div, no html tags) :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.858231, 30.746574),map: map}); markers.push(marker); var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.860031, 30.77951),map: map}); markers.push(marker); var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.886429, 30.708113),map: map}); markers.push(marker); var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.89798, 30.690451),map: map}); markers.push(marker); var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.889568, 30.63323),map: map}); markers.push(marker); var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.878494, 30.833076),map: map}); markers.push(marker);
```

I am thinking if I change arackoord to load data from page, markers can move.

**What should I write from instead of arackoord ?** **How can make it Work ?**

Ps : Page name : move.jsp

Best Regards,

Comment: do you want to show only 1 marker which position will keep changing according to the time or do you want to keep adding new marker on your map according to the time?

Comment: Multiple marker @Katrin

Comment: @HaroldWren Please don't revert the edits made to your posts by the community. Do so only if you think that it changes the meaning of what you wanted to ask.

Comment: do you mean something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/4x4s5omk/1/

Comment: @Katrin yes ! Same like that :) Thank you ! I will try, If I fail, can you help ? Example : where can I put data in it ?

Comment: Sure! And no worry, there are lots of people willing to help. Cheers :)

Comment: @Katrin how can I set  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng), to inside page data ? How can I get data :) inside a function ? :)

Comment: I think you can have a backend page e.g location.jsp to generate one pair of lat, lng each time. The output can be in json format. e.g {"lat":36.858231, "lng":30.746574} 

And in your jquery code, using ajax to retrieve the data from location.jsp, and create marker using new google.maps.LatLng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frontend Javascript:

```
var map;
var lat = 36.858231 ;
var lng = 30.746574 ;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.858231, 30.746574)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

setInterval(
 function addMarker() 
 { 
     $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url: 'location.jsp',
         async: false,
         dataType:'json',
         success:function(data){
             lat = data.lat;
             lng = data.lng;
             var  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                             map: map
                           }); 
         }
     });

 }
 ,1000);
```

Backend data:
an example of location.jsp (didn't test)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    // you should have some mechanism to generate the coordinate, do not use hard code value.
    json.put("lat", 36.858231 );   
    json.put("lng", 30.746574 );
    out.print(json);
    out.flush();
%>
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4x4s5omk/2/

Comment: I did exacly you did (all of it same) but no marker appear. Json result working good.

Comment: any error message in console panel (chrome inspector/firebug)?

Comment: chrome says : "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" Error on the "   $.ajax({    " that part said.

Comment: Did you include jQuery?
put the following inside your frontend head tag

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: included but I made it comment :D So it is work, thank you :D If you have a travel plan to Antalya, please let me know :)

Comment: last question, I swear I never distrub you again :D I have multiple coordinates so need multiple markers, json return a data like this : {"lng":"30.722729","lat":"36.868237"}{"lng":"30.723206","lat":"36.868256"}{"lng":"30.663265","lat":"36.904949"}{"lng":"30.691847","lat":"36.895805"}{"lng":"30.63323","lat":"36.889568"}{"lng":"30.826973","lat":"36.871365"}{"lng":"30.826973","lat":"36.871365"}{"lng":"30.663265","lat":"36.904949"}{"lng":"30.691847","lat":"36.895805"}{"lng":"30.722729","lat":"36.868237"} how can do it with multiple markers ? No marker seen again, also no error

Comment: try to generate your json like this:
[{"lng":30.722729,"lat":36.868237},{"lng":30.723206,"lat":36.868256},{"lng":30.663265,"lat":36.904949},{"lng":30.691847,"lat":36.895805}]

and in your ajax, loop through them like following:
$.each(data, function(index) {
             lat = data[index].lat;
             lng = data[index].lng;
             var  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                             map: map
                           }); 
         });

Comment: I did but I am taking an error success:$.each(data, function(index){
            var lat = data[index].lat;
            var lng = data[index].lng;
            
             var  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                             map: map
                           }); 
         });  ////////////////////// here from this "   ;  "  if I remove this taking  error on the top
         
     });

Comment: the $.each loop should be placed inside the "function(data){}" 
 i.e
success:function(data){
  $.each(data,function(index){...});
}

Comment: if I can give more than 1 point, I will give 100 points :D It is working :D http://i62.tinypic.com/4vhcft.jpg Just need some clear map I think :D Thank you again ! :)